# delete the previous file with newone on update in laravel

Tags: laravel, file, controller, updates, laravel-8

what happen to my update file?

I can't update file in my program, what's wrong with my controller?

**edit.blade.php**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        {{ Form::model($activityreports,['route'=>['activityreports.update',$activityreports['id']], 'files'=>true, 'method'=>'GET', 'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']) }}
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                @if(!empty($errors->all()))
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    {{ Html::ul($errors->all())}}
                </div>
                @endif
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{ Form::label('file', 'Laporan Kegiatan') }}
                            {{ Form::file('file', ['class'=>'form-control']) }}        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- </form> -->
        {{ Form::close() }}
    </div>
</div>
```

**controller**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
        $rules=[
             
            'title'=>'required',
            'date'=>'required',
            'type'=>'required',
            'place'=>'required'
        ];
 
        $pesan=[
            'title.required'=>'Judul Kegiatan Tidak Boleh Kosong',
            'date.required'=>'Tanggal Kegiatan Tidak Boleh Kosong',
            'type.required'=>'Jenis Kegiatan Tidak Boleh Kosong',
            'place.required'=>'Lokasi Kegiatan Tidak Boleh Kosong',
        ];
 
 
        $validator=Validator::make(Input::all(),$rules,$pesan);
 
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::to('admin/activityreports/'.$id.'/edit')
            ->withErrors($validator);
 
        }else{
            $fileName="";
 
            $activityreports=Activityreports::find($id);

            if($request->hasFile('file')){
                Storage::delete($activityreports->file);

                $file=$request->file('file');
                $fileName=$file->getClientOriginalName();
                $file->move('storage/file/activityreportsFile/', $fileName);
                $activityreports->file=$fileName;  
            }
                
            $activityreports->title=Input::get('title');
            $activityreports->date=Input::get('date');
            $activityreports->type=Input::get('type');
            $activityreports->place=Input::get('place');
            $activityreports->save();
 
            Session::flash('message','Data Berhasil Diubah');
             
            return Redirect::to('admin/activityreports/index');
        }
```

I tried another code and there is error 'Call to member function getClientOriginalName on null. And when I make file required then input file, there is always warning to input .pdf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**, wehre is the problem which causes the error:

This line `$file=$request->file('file');` sets  `$file`to null, therefore you cannot call the function in the next line.
This means that no file is present in your request. You can check your request if you call `dd($request->all())` in your update method.

**Second**, why does this happen?

I think your problem is that you create a GET form in your view and therefore a GET request will be sent. You will probably have to make a POST request (you could also make a PATCH request since you call the update method in your controller).

Please change the form to POST and your route to POST and try it again.